# JasperException while processing jsp page

Tags: apache, jsp

I have a JSP file which has the following code in a try block:

```
String AccountName = request.getParameter("accountName");

String[] b=AccountName.split("/");
String c=b[0];

String s="select * from account_version where acc_id in (Select acc_id from account where acc_name="+"'"+c+"'"+")";
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(s);
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Account_Version");
HSSFRow rowhead = sheet.createRow((short) 0);
rowhead.createCell((short) 0).setCellValue("Line ID");
rowhead.createCell((short) 1).setCellValue("Account ID");
rowhead.createCell((short) 2).setCellValue("Version Number");
rowhead.createCell((short) 3).setCellValue("Chargable FTE");
rowhead.createCell((short) 4).setCellValue("Cost Call Date");
rowhead.createCell((short) 5).setCellValue("Is Approved");

int i = 1;
while (rs.next()){
    HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow((short) i);
    row.createCell((short) 0).setCellValue(rs.getInt("line_id"));
    row.createCell((short) 1).setCellValue(rs.getInt("acc_id"));
    row.createCell((short) 2).setCellValue(rs.getInt("version_no"));
    row.createCell((short) 3).setCellValue(rs.getInt("chargable_fte"));
    row.createCell((short) 4).setCellValue(rs.getDate("cost_call_date"));
    row.createCell((short) 5).setCellValue(rs.getBoolean("is_approved"));

    i++;
}
String yemi = "C:/Users/IBM_ADMIN/Desktop/test.xls";
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(yemi);
workbook.write(fileOut);
fileOut.close();
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (SQLException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

In this file whenever I am including the following lines I am getting an exception:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page
```

whereas without these 2 lines, the file runs fine:

```
String[] b=AccountName.split("/");
String c=b[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Before splitting string try to print AccountName value. I guess slash (/) is not available in variable that is why you are getting this error.

**

```
String AccountName = request.getParameter("accountName");
System.out.println(AccountName);
```

**